# What is the most efficient way to format strings with rounding and thousand separator in C?

Tags: c, string, locale, rounding

So I have an inner loop situation with a buffer of floating point and integer values that are to be copied over to a another buffer in string format.

What are my alternatives to round and insert a thousand separator when formatting strings? Whatever the approach I end up using, it has to be flexible enough in permitting different formats. Also, because this is a inner loop scenario, I want to optimize any solution as far as possible.

It would seem `locale.h` is one way to do it. But in that case, how can I setup customized locales, and how do I actually use them? Or is there a better alternative altogether? If this is a noob question please just point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

Here are a few examples to clarify:

`1000` gives `1,000` (If I want to use `,` as thousand separator)

`1000` gives `1 000` (If I want to use `space` as thousand separator)

`1000.123` gives `1,000.1` (If I want to round to one digit and use `,` as thousand separator)

`0` gives `` (If I want to show zero as a blank string)

I am on a POSIX system btw...

Comment: Is C++ okay?  Or does it need to be plain-old C?

Comment: @csd: Sorry, C only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set a locale using `setlocale` and use printf with the `'` flag and a precision value for rounding. Whether this will work, depends on your C library.

See the following program:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double value = 1234567890.123;

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Locale not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%'.0f\n", value);
    printf("%'.1f\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

On my Ubuntu system, the output is:

```
1,234,567,890
1,234,567,890.1
```

Comment: It simply enables the thousands' separator of the current locale.

Comment: is it possible to change the separetor? using space instead

Comment: Not really. You could try to find a locale the uses space as thousands' separator. The French locale usually uses a space character, but it uses comma as decimal separator. If you want a portable solution, you have to write your own formatting functions.